# How can I separate str in column of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I create a new column with separate player names and team names in dataframe?

```
                             Name  Age    Position   Apps  Mins Tackles Inter Fouls Offsides Clear  Drb Blocks OwnG  Rating
0         Conor Bradley Liverpool   20        D(R)      5   386     3.0   0.6   1.2      0.2   1.2  1.4      -    -    7.72
1             Bukayo Saka Arsenal   22        D(L)     25  2139     2.0   0.4   1.2        -   0.5    1    0.1    -    7.71
2                  Rodri Man City   27        D(C)     23  1990     2.1   0.9   1.3        -   1.4  0.8    0.3    -    7.58
3    Michael Olise Crystal Palace   22     AM(CLR)   8(3)   755     1.3   0.5   0.6        -   0.7  1.1      -    -    7.54
4         Mohamed Salah Liverpool   31     AM(CLR)  20(1)  1790     0.6   0.1   0.3        -     -  0.6      -    -    7.48
570    Thiago Alcântara Liverpool   32        M(C)   0(1)     5       -     -     -        -     -    -      -    -    5.89
571         Anass Zaroury Burnley   23       AM(L)   1(5)   149     0.2     -   0.7        -   0.2  0.7      -    -    5.85
572            Ryan One Sheff Utd   17  Midfielder   0(1)     7       -     -     -        -     -    -      -    -    5.81
573            Luke Harris Fulham   18       AM(C)   0(1)    74       1     -     2        -     -    1      -    -    5.73
574       Andrei Radu Bournemouth   26          GK      2   180       -     -     -        -   0.5    -      -    -    5.70
```

```
temp = data2['Player.1'].str.split(',')

for i in range(len(temp)):
    n = temp[i][0]
    name.append(n)
data2['Name']= name

for i in range(len(temp)):
    a = temp[i][1]
    age.append(a)
data2['Age']= age
```

I separated it by using `.split(',')` but it failed because there was no comma between the player name and the team name

Comment: IMO hardly can you do this, unless you have a list of all possible team names.

Comment: "How can I create a new column..."  What a new column in a **picture** ????  Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)

Answer (score 2):

What about using [(*NER*) Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) ?

On the provided sample, 19/20 players (+teams) were correctly recognized by the [`Jean-Baptiste/roberta-large-ner-english`](https://huggingface.co/Jean-Baptiste/roberta-large-ner-english) model. For the missing players (ie. Conor Bradley), you can do some *post-processing* to extract them.

[image]

That being said, if your dataset is exclusive to the Premier League, a simpler approach would be to obtain an exhaustive/updated list of the clubs (*like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Premier_League_clubs) one from wikipedia*) and do some classic text processing using regex.

```
clubs = (
    pd.read_html(
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Premier_League_clubs",
        attrs={"class": "wikitable"},
    )[0]["Clubs"].str.split(",\s*").explode()
    .replace( # you may need to add more like these below..
        {"Manchester": "Man", "United": "Utd", "Sheffield": "Sheff"},
        regex=True
    )
)

import re; pat = r"(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, clubs))

df["Team"] = df["Name"].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
df["Player"] = df["Name"].replace(pat, "", regex=True).str.strip()
```

Output :

```
print(df.loc[:, ["Name", "Team", "Player"]])

                             Name            Player            Team
0         Conor Bradley Liverpool     Conor Bradley       Liverpool
1             Bukayo Saka Arsenal       Bukayo Saka         Arsenal
2                  Rodri Man City             Rodri        Man City
3    Michael Olise Crystal Palace     Michael Olise  Crystal Palace
4         Mohamed Salah Liverpool     Mohamed Salah       Liverpool
570    Thiago Alcântara Liverpool  Thiago Alcântara       Liverpool
571         Anass Zaroury Burnley     Anass Zaroury         Burnley
572            Ryan One Sheff Utd          Ryan One       Sheff Utd
573            Luke Harris Fulham       Luke Harris          Fulham
574       Andrei Radu Bournemouth       Andrei Radu     Bournemouth
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to grab the first two words from your column with the player names and their team. This only works assuming they have one first name and one last name:

```
x = re.search("(.+\s+.+)\s", Name)
```

Instead of assigning it to x fill your column with it.

Comment: This will not work. As you can see, there's [Rodri Man City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodri_(footballer%2C_born_1996)) who doesn't fit your pattern.

Comment: But his name is rodri man, have you never heard of him?

Comment: Well, I googled for _"Rodri Man"_ but couldn't find a connection with the guy. I've only found him mentioned as _"Rodri"_ in connection to the Manchester City F.C. which has a short name [_"Man City"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_City_F.C.). So the record `"Rodri Man City"` should be splitted as `["Rodri",  "Man City"]`. In any case, the point is that names cannot be expected to consist of only two words.

Comment: I already stated it would only work in 90% of the cases.